# How to send message from user to user in WeChat via web api?

Tags: wechat

What I want to do is send a message from a normal user account to another user account. It has to be sent via web api, calling the corresponding URL.

I can't find any related information.

Comment: Any luck on this part ?

Comment: Unfortunately no...